# Export JavaFX project to android

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafxports

I have a project made in `JavaFX` and want to run it in Android. I have used `JavaFXports` and have generated the needed apk. Also I managed to install the apk on an emulator. But I need the sources(the source code). In other words I want to be able to debug the project while it is running on the emulator.

Comment: It is possible to debug the project with the JavaFX source from your IDE and Android Monitor, at least with the project running on a real Android device. What emulator are you using?

Comment: From android studio Nexus_5X_API_21

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, with a JavaFX project, then probably debugging will _just_ work out of the box. Have you tried it?

Comment: I will try but don't think it will. I just start the emulator from android studio. While i am installing the apk from the cmd

Comment: But how did you create the apk in the first place? With the JavaFXPorts plugin in an IDE different than Android Studio?

Comment: I used this tutorial https://breekmd.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/javafx-on-android-with-javafxports/

Comment: And how did you managed to install the apk in the emulator? There is a known issue (`INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS`) that prevents that (intel architecture not supported). Are you using an Armeabi image? That works but it is terrible slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To debug a JavaFXPorts/Gluon Mobile that you have created using the Gluon plugin for your IDE (NetBeans, IntelliJ or Eclipse), and that you have deployed to the Android emulator (using Android Studio), follow these steps:

**1. Create the JavaFX mobile app from your IDE**

For that you can use the Gluon [plugin](http://gluonhq.com/get-started/ide-plugins/) for your IDE. Use one of the built-in templates to create your project or go and use one of the many samples available [here](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/).

Let's say you use the Single View project. Provide a name and run the app

[image]

**2. Create the apk**

Run the task `Tasks->Android->Android` to create the apk (or on command line run `./gradlew android`).

**3. Run the emulator**

For this, open Android Studio, create a new empty app from a template, and click on run. It will ask you to select a device. Then create a new virtual device and use an ARMEABI image.

[image: armeabi image]

While this image is really, really slow, the x86-64 image won't work to deploy the apk (see INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS [error](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/65/emulator)). So if you can't get a real device to test it, this is the only solution as far as I know.

If needed, download the armeabi image. Once you have it, it will take quite a while to launch the app. But just need the emulator, so there is no need to wait, and we can close the emulator, and before closing Android Studio, get the image name, let's say `Nexus_5_API_23`.

On command line, go to `<android sdk>/tools` and run:

```
./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23
```

It will show up, and you will see something like:

```
$ ./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

[image]

**4. Deploy the apk**

On command line, go to `<android sdk>/platform-tools` and run

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install <path.to>/<your.app>.apk
```

You can find the apk in your project under `/builds/javafxports/android/<your.app>.apk`.

```
$adb -s emulator-5554 install GluonDebugEmulator.apk                                         
[100%] /data/local/tmp/GluonDebugEmulator.apk                                                                                       
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/GluonDebugEmulator.apk
Success
```

**5. Run the apk on the emulator**

[image]

**6. Open Android Device Monitor**

Go to `<android sdk>/tools` and run `monitor`. On the left, on top you should see the emulator device, and a list of processes. Find your app package name there, select it and see the port it is using for the app (8700).

[image: monitor]

**7. Attach the debugger on your IDE**

Finally, go back to your IDE, and under Debug options, attach a debugger, with localhost and 8700. This is for NetBeans:

[image]

and click ok. A debugging process will start.

**8. Start debugging**

Add a breakpoint in your code, for instance in the button event handler, and click on the button in the app running on the emulator. You will see that it stops in the breakpoint.

[image: debugging]

And this is it.