# install gluom App ADT via ADB and I get error"INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS"

Tags: android, adb, adt, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I try to install my app that build usin javafxports via ADB, or copy apk and install.
bat i got error.

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install MyApp.apk
adb: failed to install MyApp.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

I use [**android studio emulator**],[**virtualBox**],[**MEmu**]

android target [**Android 5.1**]

Comment: Duplicated of [Deploying to an Android emulator shows error INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398426/deploying-to-an-android-emulator-shows-error-install-failed-no-matching-abis).

Comment: I dont want use BlueStacks. I want use old version of andreoid 5.1.

Comment: is this good solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473570/11243997)

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538097/export-javafx-project-to-android/44544233#44544233)

Answer (score 1):

Since my previous answer was not technical enough, basically one solution is to set the following parameters to fix the issue:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

but since the plugin doesn't expose those parameters or there is not enough information, I did the following:

I installed the NDK locally, modified the `application.mk` file under `jni/` directory and added all the architectures list arguments (it's easy to find on `application.mk`). Then, I passed the NDK that I installed locally as an argument for the `client:build`, `client:package`, `client:compile` etc...

It worked and the apks were produced as per that fix. BUT,

After disabling Play security on Android and signing the apk using apkverify and attempted also to install via adb to the device, all of them produced the same error "App not installed". As for the emulator, I still got the same error the asker of the question got despite the fact everything seems setup correctly and didn't miss anything in the documentation provided by Gluon.

I hope this answer is better.

Maybe I missed something but this might help.

You can find more information about NDK here: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android